# igraph - multiple lines of text in one circle?

Tags: r, igraph

I am a complete beginner to igraph so please be easy on me. I am creating a network map and would like to add additional lines of text for each circle. How may I do that? Is it possible? Here is an illustration:

[image]

Comment: Can you post code that you've already tried? A minimal example would help with sample data so we can run it and try it as well.

Answer (score 11):

You can specify a line break in a character vector using `\n`, which allows you to force multiple lines of text in a single vertex.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(A=1,B=2))
V(g)$name <- c("Line 1\nLine 2","Point 2")
plot(g,vertex.size=100)
```

[image]