# Convert a .jpg or .png to a pdf in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm creating network images using igraph and can't seem to get them nicely into a .pdf, so I'm wondering if there is an R package to read in a .jpg/.png and then convert it to a .pdf?

Comment: I believe it would be more productive to solve your root problem, i.e., how to write network images to PDF. Create a reproducible example and show what you are doing now.

Comment: To get started, try typing `pdf('eg.pdf')` in your console, then pasting in the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23463738/980833) as a minimal example of an igraph, then finally typing `dev.off()`. Does that not produce a pdf file named `'eg.pdf'`? If it does but you don't like the results, what specifically don't you like about it?

Comment: If you can create jpeg and png files, you can create pdf files the same way, just use `pdf()`. If this does not work for you, then please show us your code.

Comment: Totally agree with roland, josh & gabor that you should give it a go with `pdf()` output. However, if you're in a hurry, you could temporarily install [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (cross-platform) and run `convert image.png image.pdf` to get your pdf output. You could also try creating an rmarkdown file and knitting the output to PDF.

Comment: ok i'll try it out and try to reproduce the gobleegook that resulted